# Get Linux server time from windows service c#

Tags: c#, linux, windows-services

Is there anyway I can get linux server time from windows service given linux server IP ? I tried to use Cliwrap (https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliWrap) and wrote the following function but it is not working as well:

```
public string GetLinuxServerTime()
    {
        using (var cli = new Cli("bash.exe"))
        {
            // Execute
            var output = cli.Execute("ssh user@10.104.12.114 date");
            return "abc";
        }
    }
```

Kindly suggest some another way.

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: It is giving the following error: 
"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Is the folder to "bash" in the PATH variable for the system? Does it work if you give an absolute path instead of just "bash.exe"?

Comment: Yes. It works. 
May be it needs user credentials?

Comment: Can you suggest the work around? @john

Comment: time must be same on all servers, because all of them should synchronize time with time servers, the difference may only in timezone. So there is no reason to determine time from linux server. May be better to describe your problem to get proper solution?

Comment: Actually, I need to get the date time of all the client servers and need to check if they are synchronized with the single NTP server. Some servers are windows based and some are Linux Based. I am able to get the other windows server time and able to compare it with NTP server as well. But unable to get the linux server time. @ПавелМарченко

Comment: @K132221ZaheerAbbas I have used sharSSH in my projects before, so you cant try it also. For command you provided you should have the public key to connect the server. If you haven't, you should provide password i.e. ssh user:password@host command. Also you should set PATH variable to your binaries or use absolute path to avoid error "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: You probably don't have public key authentication configured properly on either your client or the Linux machine. In any case, the Linux machine should all be syncing with an NTP server. If they get out of sync, there would be messages in the log file. You can test the pk auth by attempting to connect with an ssh client using your above connection info. I've never used cliwrap. Are you sure it upports PK Auth? (I assume PK because you're not supplying a password).